# Creating view with an auto incremeting ID column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

The view I am creating is loosing the Primary key of the main table as I use the aggregate function.

But, I need one unique ID in my view to use it to create a dashboard. Can I create a dummy unique column with auto incremented value in SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [ROW_NUMBER(](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)) function to generate a unique value for each row.

Although one might ask why you'd need a unique ID after aggregation, and how the dashboard would use an arbitrary value instead of, say, the columns you've used to aggregate the data.

Comment: The Dashboard I am using is the Smart bear Fusion Chart. http://www.softwareplanner.com/UsersGuide_Dashboard.pdf    For the Parameter setting it has some different way to compare...so I nees an unique column.